# How do the tags in blog posts work? Do they implement a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, tags, many-to-many, blogs

I’m new to Node JS and MongoDB and I’ve always had a burning question: How does the tagging work for blog posts?

As I slowly learn about MongoDB, I am trying to comprehend how this tagging system work, but can’t seem to understand a few things.

I understand that there would a many-to-many relationship between the blog posts and the tags, but from what I know about the MongoDB documents’ 16Mb limit, I can’t seem to understand how potentially millions of blog posts or their IDs could be placed under one tag document.

As I said I am still new to MongoDB and stilling getting a handle of schemas and the process of embedding values from one collection to another, so if anyone knows about this topic, I would appreciate even a high-level explanation or an example schema that might highlight how the 16Mb limit isn’t exceed.

For example, let’s say that there are thousands of blog posts with the tag ‘dog’ in them, how would querying for all the posts with the tag ‘dog’ be achieved?

How would track all the posts with this tag?
Would you have a separate collection for ‘posts’ and one for ‘tags’, and have a many to many relationship?

I've tried researching online for blog posts and tags, and even tried reading the MongoDB docs but couldn't really find anything to answer my questions.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we don't store post's id in the tag but the tag id in the post.
So we don't have `dog` collection with a list of post id with the `dog` tag,
but a collection of posts, all owning their `tags` property wich contain the tags list's id.

So we can "easily" request all posts with X or Y tag (`dog` for example) without having a tag collection owning each post id.